# Speakers are not working

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I own a Sony Laptop model VGN FN21L and the speakers have stopped working I also have  no sound from the headphone socket.Windows Vista is installed,can anyone help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if also the headphone socket is not working, it's definitely a software issue.

first check if driver is installed and working correctly by right clicking on `Computer` and selecting `Manage` and clicking on `Device manager` on the left panel

then check if default audio player is not set to another device and make sure it's turned on and unmuted.

also you can check your laptop or headphone with another one.